# ANOSIM with cutree groupings

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, vegan, hclust

What i would like to do is an ANOSIM of defined groupings in some assemblage data to see whether the groupings are significantly different from one another, in a similar fashion to this example code:

```
data(dune)
data(dune.env)
dune.dist <- vegdist(dune)
attach(dune.env)
dune.ano <- anosim(dune.dist, Management)
summary(dune.ano)
```

However in my own data I have the species abundance in a bray-curtis matrices and after creating hclust() diagrams and creating my own groupings visually by looking at the dendrogram and setting the height. I can then through cutree() get these groupings which can be superimposed on MDS plots etc. but I would like to check the significance of the similarity between the groupings i have created - i.e are the groupings significantly different or just arbitrary groupings?

e.g.

```
data("dune")
dune.dist <- vegdist(dune)
clua <- hclust(dune.dist, "average")
plot(clua)
rect.hclust(clua, h =0.65)
c1 <- cutree(clua, h=0.65)
```

I then want to use the c1 defined category as the groupings, which in the example code given was the management factor, and test their similarities to see whether they are actually different via anosim().

I am pretty sure this is just a matter of my inept coding.... any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cutree` returns groups as integers: you must change these to factors if you want to use them in `anosim`: Try `anosim(vegdist(dune), factor(c1))`. You better contact a local statistician for using `anosim` to analyse dissimilarities using clusters created from these very same dissimilarities.

Comment: Thank you for the input @JariOksansen. I am guessing from the comment that trying to analyse dissimilarities based on clusters from the same dissimilarities is speculative route to go down?? I will look into whether I can get some stats assistance from my university, as my data unlike the papers I have read using a similar analytical approach have treatments or location groupings to apply the ANOSIM to - mine is a time series, so perhaps this is not so appropriate.